# How to make it clickable kml file that has been google maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have uploaded a kml file into google maps. Now i need to make it clickable. Can there is a way to do this. or I need to upload by code only?

Comment: If you have not already seen it, the [**KML Tutorial**](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut) may be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code below you will upload a kml file into Google Maps. If you'll click the polygon in the map center, a balloon will pop-up the feature's attributes.

My advice for you is to study the [polygons.kml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/polygons.kml) file, and to be very careful when building the kml elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html { height: 100% }
            body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
            #map-canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/polygons.kml';
            function initialize() {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.417495,28.015405);
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                    mapOptions);
                loadKmlLayer(src, map);
                function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
                    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
                        map: map
                    });
                }
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"/></div>
    </body>
</html>
```